# Connecting Azure function app to SQL Server DB in Azure VM using python trigger

Tags: python, sql-server, azure-functions, pyodbc, azure-virtual-machine

We have a SQL Server DB setup on Azure VM. We are trying to create an Azure Function App with Python timerTrigger that will make an API call and store result of that into our DB.

Able to make the API call via Azure function successfully and read that data, but getting issues while writing into DB.

ERROR Snippet:

```
Result: Failure Exception: OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)') Stack: File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 357, in _handle__function_load_request func = loader.load_function( File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/utils/wrappers.py", line 44, in call return func(*args, **kwargs) File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/loader.py", line 132, in load_function mod = importlib.import_module(fullmodname) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py",
```

CODE Snippet:

import pyodbc
def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=<HOSTNAME/IP>;Database=<DB NAME>;UID=<USERNAME>;PWD=<PASSWORD>;Trusted_Connection=yes;')

# also tried with this:
#cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=<HOSTNAME/IP>;DATABASE=<DB NAME>;Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = cnxn.cursor()

sel = ("SELECT top 2 * FROM schema.our_table;")
cursor.execute(sel)

for row in cursor.fetchall():
        print(row)
```

When running from pycharm in the Azure VM where DB is setup, I can run same code and get results, but when running via Azure Function, it keeps failing with error:  Login timeout expired (0)

When running from pycharm in the Azure VM where DB is setup, I can run same code and get results, but when running via Azure Function, it keeps failing with error:  Login timeout expired (0)

Comment: Choose one authentication method. `UID=...;PWD=...;` is used for SQL Logon authentication, where a username+password based login is created on the SQL Server instance itself. `Trusted_Connection=yes;` is used for Windows/Active Directory authentication and relies on the process making the connection to be executing in the context of a particular account that's already known to the SQL Server instance by way of User/Group memberships. `Trusted_Connection=yes;` overrides SQL Logon authentication.

Comment: thanks for responding, i tried removing it and it fails with same error

Comment: What's the full and complete error message as text? Does it include `Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [5]`, which indicates that it's trying to use RPC ports? What happens if you force it to use the TCP/IP client driver with the `tcp:` prefix, i.e.: `Server=tcp:YourServerNameOrIpAddressHere;`

Comment: Result: Failure Exception: OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)') Stack: File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 452, in _handle__invocation_request call_result = await self._loop.run_in_executor( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs) File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 718, in _run_sync_func

Answer (score 0):

Issue got resolved as there was some IP Address issue. And upon changing the IP Address, I was able to query the database.

Comment: Please submit the exact steps you did to came out with the solution.